Android: How to add app launcher on home sceen
After installing an app, I would like to add the app launcher on home screen. I would also like to know if the app launcher can be added at the first available slot, instead of adding it to the last slot on home screen. For example, if a user has uninstalled an app, which was on home screen, then that slot would be empty. Is there a way to place my app launcher at that slot?
I was going through the ShortcutManager, but I couldn't get what I am looking for.
